# in Java when Using Hibernate for CRUD how could we access a Header value from the initial Resteasy request

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, quarkus, quarkus-panache

please I need help from a Java expert.

I would like to store the **user** how modified the record in a field of a database table using Hibernate’s `@PreUpdate`.

The user name is set in header field `x-remote-user` by the reverse proxy. I can access it as shown below

```java
@GET
@Path("/getuser")
public String get( @HeaderParam("x-remote-user") String userName) {
  return userName;
}
```

Is there a way to inject `@HeaderParam` in my JPA entity bean? Should I lookup reflections?

This didn’t work:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_companies")
public class TBusiness extends PanacheEntityBase {
  @Column(name = "company_name", nullable = true)
  public String companyName;
  @Column(name = "updated_by", nullable = true)
  public String updatedBy;
  
  @PreUpdate
  public void preUpdate(@HeaderParam("x-remote-user") String userName) {
    updatedBy = userName;
  }
}
```

---

Let me reformulate my question

I am using Panache data REST CRUD generation

Is there a way to have access to the header value that holds the username from a `@RequestScoped` class

Then use this value in the JPA entities on `@PreUpdate`?

Comment: Hello,
how could I write code to access a variable from RESTEASY in a JPA entity? I have no idea so I tried injection by annotations.

Comment: how can I do that with RESTEasy and store the result in a variable that can be accessed by the JPA entity for that session that won't be shared with other REST requests?

Comment: I Have no idea about Reflection in java, but could it be useful here? thanks

Comment: Can't you simply pass the `userName` param from the REST endpoint to the service layer persisting the entity bean?

Comment: I am using [quarkus rest-data-panache](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-data-panache). I only have a class `public interface BusinessResource extends PanacheEntityResource<TBusiness, Integer> {` the details are generated automatically. Is there a way to do that at this level?

Comment: Let me reformulate my question
I am using Panache REST CRUD generation
Is there a way to have access to the header value that holds the username from a `@RequestScoped` class
Then use this value in the JPA entities on `@PreUpdate`?

Comment: Don't have experience with Quarkus, I believe it implements a subset of the CDI spec. You could move the `@PreUpdate` method to an entity listener. In it you could inject a `@RequestScoped` bean that extracts the header. Reference the entity listener with the `@EntityListeners` annotation in the entity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this to work by adding undertow dependency :

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

then in an `EntityListener` class created below `PrePersist` method:

```java
@RequestScoped
// @Path("api/v1/Header")
public class AuditingEntityListener {
  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AuditingEntityListener.class);

  // Inject the bean so that Quarkus does not remove it at build time (IMPORTANT)
  @Inject
  HttpServletRequest requestNotUsed;

  @PrePersist
  void onPrePersist(TBusiness myEntity) {
    HttpServletRequest HSR = CDI.current().select(HttpServletRequest.class).get();
    LOG.info("HSR getRequestHeader user: " + HSR.getHeader("x-remote-user"));
  }
}
```